# Unable to access other flas movieclip into the Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am creating a structure in Action Script 3 using Adobe Animate CC and there are index.fla where I am attaching document class Main.as. I am able to access all the movieclips which are created in Main.fla but I also created a other fla (mainmenu.fla) but I am unable to access movieclips into other class (Mainmenu.as) which are created in mainmenu.fla.

Comment: Naturally you won't be able to, FLA is the working file, like a supermarket with many objects in it. Both supermarkets sell pringles, but supermarket A cannot sell(or in this case, access) the pringles from supermarket B. You can only sell your own pringles lol. What you want to do is to combine both the assets from the two fla into one, and use a single movieclip to represent Main / MainMenu each

Answer (score 0):

Export that `mainmenu` as an SWF file.

Then in `Main` project file you can load the SWF and access its variables. **mainmenu.fla** must be first **compiled** (*ie:* packaged) in order to be usable in another app.